# Tool recommendation for versioned, permission controlled custom list management

Tags: sharepoint, crud

I'm not sure where to ask this question, I'm hoping it wont' be closed as "off topic" or "opinion based". If it turns out to be that, can you please suggest where this question can be asked instead?

I have a very specific set of requirements for custom list management tool I'm trying to find:

- Custom lists, ability to add new custom fields easily
- Ability to use either predefined set of values (combo box) or free form text/numeric/etc fields
- Ability to validate entered data via regex
- Data in the list is version controlled
- Lists are group/role-based permission controlled (only certain lists can be updated by certain people, certain people can only READ data, but not update, etc)
- Rest web services to update list data via a script

An example of such tool is SharePoint, but I find it very difficult to work with. Looking for something similar in the Linux world.

Comment: There's [softwarerecs.se] to ask for software recommendations.

Comment: I will create the question there. Thanks.